# Image display issue, Neural Style Transfer

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I am attempting to read in my own images in python following the tensorflow [Neural Style Transfer](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/style_transfer) tutorial and when displaying them they look nothing like the original image. Can someone please explain why this is? Is it because of the tensorflow preprocessing? Ultimately my issue with Neural Style Transfer is the style never changes [(whole code here)](https://github.com/kstisser/GANPlayground/blob/main/neuralStyleTransfer.py). I'm always getting a rainbow style applied, no matter what the style image is, and I'm wondering if this is the issue?

Simple code of how I'm reading in images and displaying for debugging:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

style_image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(Image.open('blackGold.jpg'))

plt.imshow(style_image)
plt.show()
cv2.imshow("img", style_image)
```

Original Image:
[image]

Displaying with matplotlib:
[image]

Displaying with opencv:
[image]

Neural Style Transfer results:
[image]

I appreciate any input, thanks!

Comment: `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array` returns a `float` image, thus you see clipping for all values above `1.0`. Use `style_image.astype(np.uint8)`, and you get proper output for both methods. The color mismatch between OpenCV and Matplotlib comes from the different used color orderings, BGR (OpenCV) vs. RGB (Matplotlib).

Answer (score 1):

Normalize the image, divide the values of your input image, which usually range from 0-255, by 255 so the images are in range of 0-1